# swift 4 decoder STRUCT MAPPING JSON

Tags: json, swift, xcode, serialización

tengo esta estructura de json y lo que quiero hacer por ahora solo es imprimirla en consola, estoy aprendiendo a mapear un json
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

my struct:

```
struct Buscajson: Decodable {

        let status: Int?
        let mensaje:String?
        let empresas: empresa?
    }

    struct empresa: Decodable {

        let id :Int?
        let nombre :String?
        let sitioweb :String?
        let logo : String?
        let fechaFundacion :String?
        let fundadores :[fundador]?
        let productos :[producto]?


    }     struct fundador:Decodable {

        let nombre:String
        let foto:String
    }

    struct producto: Decodable {

        let nombre:String
        let icono:String

    }
```

y aqui esta mi codigo :

```
    let JSONurlString = "http://payrapid.net/API/LoginBecariosPost.php?user=Apple&password=@PPL3?"

    guard let url = URL(string: JSONurlString) else { return }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in



        guard let data = data else { return }

        do {

            let buscado = try JSONDecoder().decode(Buscajson.self, from: data)
            print(buscado)




        } catch let jsonError {

        print("error en la serializacion de json",jsonError)
        }




        }.resume()
}
```

pero cuando trato de imprimir en consola empresa me sale nulo, entcs mi pregunta es como represento a empresa en la estructura para que lea los demas campos ?:

Buscajson #1(status: Optional(1), mensaje: Optional("Inicio de sesión con éxito"), empresas: nil)

como puedo imprimir lo demas que contienen con estructuras , o no se puede, seria solo con ciclos for y NSDictionary y NSArray ,NSObject y todo eso ?

Comment: Por favor, puedes [edit] tu pregunta para hacerla legible. Básicamente formatea correctamente el JSON que menciones,  el código y las imágenes que no se visualizan

Comment: o k ,   g r a c i as

Answer (score 0):

En el json que recibes como respuesta, la llave del objeto es *empresa* y no *empresas* (nótese la "s" del plural) por lo que el *parsing* falla.

Tienes dos opciones:

1. Cambiar la definición del *struct* Buscajson a:

   ```
   struct Buscajson : Codable {
       let status   : Int?
       let mensaje  : String?
       let empresa  : Empresa?
   }
   ```
2. Para especificar las llaves, puedes agregar un `enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey` :

   ```
   struct Buscajson : Decodable {

       let status   : Int?
       let mensaje  : String?
       let empresas : Empresa?

       enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
           case status
           case mensaje
           case empresas = "empresa"
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: muchas gracias lo probaré

Comment: Tengo una duda, porque se usa un struct en vez de una clase ?

Comment: @Popularfan Las `clases` son tipos con semántica de paso por referencia, mientras que los `struct` lo son por valor. Las `clases` soportan herencia, no así los `struct`. Por todo esto los `struct` son útiles para para almacenar los datos, las `clases`, para el comportamiento.

Comment: Ok gracias por tu respuesta